# how does socket.io works or it's architecture

Tags: node.js, http, socket.io

I am new to socket.io so I want to know how does the data in emitted in real time

I am not sure about this but is this what happens behind the scene

```
In Live chat application like whats app:

1) users send http request for handshake and server sends response if connection is establish
2) After connection is establish, if user1 sends a message then it goes to server and from there it goes to user2?
and user1 doesn't get any response after getting message from socket?
```

I am really confused in the second step, how does messages are being transmitted, I know that it's not peer to peer connection and it's not HTTP request as well ( as it doesn't come in network tab)

Thank you

Comment: It does show in the network tab. Look at the initial websocket request that opens the connection and then look in the "messages" tab of that request.

Comment: @CherryDT Yes the initial one shows in network tab but I am saying after user1 sends a message.

Also what do you mean by messages tab?

Comment: See [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjmmZ.png).

Comment: @CherryDT There's not message tab in my request https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAdBZ.png

Comment: If you don't have any `transport=websocket` requests and only `transport=polling` then websocket connections (which allow "true" pushing of messages to client) are not possible for you for some reason (e.g. reverse proxy misconfiguration). In that case socket.io resorts to polling (regular checking for updates every second or so). In this case you would find your update in one of the polling responses.

Comment: oh, if transport=websocket then when user1 sends message then it goes to the server go directly to the user2? Also I didn't find my update in one of the polling, I checked all of them

Comment: It goes to the server and the server will forward it to user2 through the still-open websocket connection that was established when the page was loaded. (not sure about your update then, hard to tell from far away)

Comment: Okay, when the request goes to the server for sending message to the user1, what is the response to user1?

Also Thankyou for your help